# Can programming tasks be taken over by artificial intelligence?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I was reading an article earlier that suggests 1/3 of us are scared their job will be taken over by robots at some point. At first I was thinking (as robots have to be programmed as well) that we, as programmers, would be safe from this. That brought me to this question.

Would artificial intelligence be capable of performing (advanced) programming tasks or would they always be limited to the level they where programmed at?

What I mean by level is, for example, a scripting language as opposed to a programming language. (Would it be even possible for a scripting language to write and compile software in a programming language?)

This topic was put on hold because the answers would be based on opinions rather than facts. Just for clarity, I am expecting answers that are based on facts. An answer that simply says yes or no would be an opinion based answer, an answer that explains why is based on facts.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, first of all, since you are dealing with the development of programs, it would be better suited to consider this a question based on [Artificial Intelligence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence), rather than [Robotics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotics). It's much more simpler to develop programs to write other programs instead of developing a physical entity to type out a program.

AI has developed to such an extent, that simple games can be played much better than what normal humans can do: [Wikipedia: Progress in AI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progress_in_artificial_intelligence).

As of now, development of complex programs is still out of the reach of AI, [though it's not far off](http://www3.imperial.ac.uk/newsandeventspggrp/imperialcollege/newssummary/news_18-12-2012-10-35-45). Still, for the most part, AI may be used to [assist human developers](http://www.philforhumanity.com/The_Use_of_Artificial_Intelligence_for_Program_Development.html) - since it's still not fully developed - rather than replace them altogether.